# Memcache Server Timeout

Tags: php, memcached

I've been seeing this error in our PHP logs all the time and can't find a real answer on the web or stack-overflow on a resoulution:

```
 MemcachePool::add(): Server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (tcp XXXXX, udp 0) failed with: Connection timed out (110)
```

This happens for one of our servers, but sometimes other servers.

This is configuration setup - we have 4 memcache server in production:

```
$memcached['servers'] = array(

"default" => array(
    'host'          => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX',
    'port'          => 'XXXXX',
    'weight'        => '25',
    'persistent'    => FALSE
),
"cluster01" => array(    

    'host'          => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX',
    'port'          => 'XXXXX',
    'weight'        => '25',
    'persistent'    => FALSE
),
"cluster02" => array(    

    'host'          => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX',
    'port'          => 'XXXXX',
    'weight'        => '25',
    'persistent'    => FALSE
),
"cluster03" => array(    

    'host'          => 'XX.XX.X.XXX',
    'port'          => 'XXXXX',
    'weight'        => '25',
    'persistent'    => FALSE
)
);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't sound like there is something necessarily wrong with your config, especially if the error is not consistent and not restricted to one server.  I would start by diagnosing TCP connections (probably with telnet) from your client machines the memcache machines.  Could be high network traffic or something along those lines causing intermittent connection failures.

Comment: My guess it would be high traffic. I do have the configuration set up to accept 3000 max connections, however there are no max connection errors in the logs. I am able to telnet to every box without an issue - so I wonder what the next steps are.